# google tag manager virtual pageview

Tags: javascript, tags, google-tag-manager, pageviews

I'm trying to set up a virtual pageview for an onclick event which generates a dialog box.

The problem I'm encountering is that the image link I'm trying to generate an event from doesn't seem to generate any kind of action when it's clicked upon (`gtm.click` or `gtm.linkClick`) even when other links/blank areas generate these events. To compound this, when using the debug tool, the dialog box generated by the click appears to remove all the html from the debug tool, however I can not see any network calls made to Google from the click.

Has anybody ecnountered this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the there is already a click event to create a dialog box - it might be that this prevents the GTM event listener from firing (afaik GTM event listeners fail when you use "return false" instead of event.preventDefault() in your event handler).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you know of a workaround as I'm working upon a 3rd party site?